# How do I show Months Grouped By Years on the horizontal Axis for a Flex Line Chart?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, flex3, linechart

Basically I have a Flex Line Chart and x-axis looks like this:

```
 ---|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|---
 November December January February   March    April     May
```

**This is fine but I also want to show the year that the months belong to, like this:**

```
 ---|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|---
 November December January February   March    April     May
       2010           |                2011
```

My dataprovider is an xml document that looks like this:

```
<Chart>
    <Month count="1"  month="November" year="2010" />
    <Month count="5"  month="December" year="2010" />
    <Month count="0"  month="January"  year="2011" />
    <Month count="10" month="February" year="2011" />
    <Month count="3"  month="March"    year="2011" />
    <Month count="9"  month="April"    year="2011" />
    <Month count="3"  month="May"      year="2011" />
</Chart>
```

And this is what I have for the LineChart control:

```
<mx:LineChart 
    height="100%" 
    width="100%" 
    dataProvider="{this._report.Month}">
    <mx:backgroundElements>
        <mx:GridLines>
            <mx:horizontalStroke>
                <mx:Stroke color="0x000000" weight="1" />
            </mx:horizontalStroke>
        </mx:GridLines>
    </mx:backgroundElements>
    <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer
            axis="{months}"
            axisStroke="{axis}"
            placement="bottom"
            tickLength="5"
            tickPlacement="outside"
            labelRotation="45">
            <mx:tickStroke>{ticks}</mx:tickStroke>
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer
            axis="{countForMonths}"
            axisStroke="{axis}"
            placement="bottom"
            tickLength="5"
            tickPlacement="outside"
            minorTickPlacement="none">
            <mx:tickStroke>{ticks}</mx:tickStroke>
        </mx:AxisRenderer>
    </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:CategoryAxis id="months" categoryField="@month"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis id="countForMonths" />
    </mx:verticalAxis>
    <mx:series>
        <mx:LineSeries
            yField="@count" 
            displayName="Report" 
            lineStroke="{myreportstroke}"/>
    </mx:series>
</mx:LineChart>
```

I have spent hours trying to find an example that does something similar with no luck.  The Flex documentation has several examples that show multiple axes on the y-axis but none for the x-axis.

I have seen several other questions posted by other people that want to do something similar but most of them never got an answer or the answer was look at the documentation for multiple axes - which I've already done.

I found [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/elixent/v3r0/topic/com.ibm.ilog.elixir.doc/Content/Visualization/Documentation/Flex/Elixir/_media/olappivot_ss1_default.png) on the IBM site for one of their Flex components.  This seems to indicate that it is possible to format the axis in the way I want.  I just need someone to steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you actually solve this problem?

Comment: No, I eventually gave up on it.  I ended up using labelFunction to format the labels on the x-axis i.e. December 2010, January 2011, February 2011, etc. I am pretty certain it is possible and I am frustrated that after hours and hours of searching that I haven't been able to find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting problem. Going to look into it. Starting point for me will be here: http://christianyates.com/blog/flex/displaying-multiple-axes-single-series-flex-charts

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have had a quick look at the link you have supplied and it does look promising.  I have put this problem aside for the moment and I will take a closer look at it when I have some spare time.